# admin backend icon fonts missing

Tags: backend, admin-panel, magento-2.0.5

As a newbie, I just installed the **M.Community Full Release with Sample Data 2.0.5 on Win8 64bit with Xampp** -- all went well so far, except arriving in the backend panel the "Admin Icons" are replaced by not resolvable symbols because the font is missing, in the *setup.css*, a font **"Admin Icons"** is referenced, which doesn't exist in any folder.

But basically, I can't find any font in any folder that actually displays icons (a Windows prob?).

[image]

Comment: You were right. It has successfully corrected errors. thank you very much

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/151125)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/151125)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that some css and fonts files are not generated properly. You need to do the folowing

1. Remove `pub/static`
2. Remove `var/cache`
3. Remove `var/composer_home`
4. Remove `var/generation`
5. Remove `var/page_cache`
6. Remove `var/view_preprocessed`
7. run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Comment: Thank you sooo much! At first I had this memory_limit runtime error (at 132M, yeah right)...but upon system restart (Windows, rrrr) it ran through again and now everything is there. *BIG eyes*...thank you so much for the quick and of course correct reply - worked like a charm, my dashboard is a-okay!

Comment: i faced same problem but when i run the command 7. it shows this msg "Failed loading /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/opcache.so:  /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/opcache.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Comment: upvoted this answer is worked!

Comment: I dont understand how to run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Comment: @CoryNickerson you must login to server using shell and then go the root folder of your magento installation. for there you can run this command

Answer (score 12):

Open up `app/etc/di.xml` find the path

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink
```

and replace it with

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy
```

Note: Remove entire files and folder under **pub/static** except **.htaccess**

Answer (score 4):

Open up `app/etc/di.xml` find the path

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink
```

and replace it with

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy
```

Then go to `var\cache` this folder remove all file

Answer (score 3):

To show backend and frontend css, font and icon , I used this solosion:

```
Remove pub/static //not .htaccess
Remove var/cache
Remove var/composer_home
Remove var/generation
Remove var/page_cache
Remove var/view_preprocessed
```

Then open up app/etc/di.xml find the path

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink
 and replace it with Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy
```

And finally run this:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Answer (score 3):

I encounted this issue when using a CDN network, I added the following to allow cross origin sharing within the html/.htaccess file

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2|font.css|css|json)$">

Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Accept-Charset,X-    Accept,Content-Type"

</FilesMatch>
```

It seemed to be an issue with the default Magento htaccess fle not allowing certain font types which caused the issue. I tried the solutions above with no success but this worked for me.

Perhaps this will help. I flushed the cache and re-indexed after adding

Answer (score 2):

check the admin panel language, and be sure to run di-compile in that language 
ex.:

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f en_US en_GB

Answer (score 1):

Open **app/etc/di.xml**

> Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink

and replace it with

> Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy

then Remove entire files and folder under pub/static except .htaccess

and it will show up

Answer (score 0):

To show backend and frontend css, font and icon, follow these 2 steps:

1.Run the deploy or forcefully deploy command:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

OR

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

2. Make sure that .htaccess file exists in `var` & `pub/static` folders after deploy, if not exists then copy and paste from the Magento original setup.

Answer (score 0):

i tried all solutions and still not working, and it is only anything related for css font icons .. ?

Comment: it was solved bu i was not able to see the new changes du to Varnish cache, as soon i cleared the cache the changes took effect ..  thanks to all (:

Answer (score 0):

plz reply quickly..i faced 2 problems..
magento icons missing and 2nd website homepage also not showing...
how i resolves these issues through c-panel.[image]

[image]

Comment: plz reply quickly..i faced 2 problems.. magento icons missing and 2nd website homepage also not showing... how i resolves these issues through c-panel.