# admin backend icon fonts missing in magento CE 2.18

Tags: magento-2.1, backend, admin-panel

I am a newbie to magento, besides the fact the it is too slow, I got to install it and the dashboard images and fonts are missing, I did some research and found this [question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/113945/admin-backend-icon-fonts-missing#)

I applied the answer but got this error when I got to this point

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

```
  [InvalidArgumentException]                                              
  There are no commands defined in the "setup:static-content" namespace.  
  Did you mean one of these?                                              
      setup                                                               
      setup:config                                                        
      setup:cron                                                          
      setup:db-data                                                       
      setup:db-schema                                                     
      setup:db                                                            
      setup:di                                                            
      setup:performance                                                   
      setup:store-config
```

By the way my php version is 7.0.12

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. `rm -rf var/cache/* var/generation/* var/page_cache/*`
2. `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`
3. `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

and see if it works.

Comment: first i appreciate the answer but in your code you did not add "php" to the prefix of the code, apart from the first one. then it updated a lot of stuff and worked but my localhost/shop page has no css it looks like webpages when sir tim beeners invented it :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are in windows server :

The issue may related to the fact that there's no Symlinks on Windows. There's 2 ways of fixing that:
1. Changing setting in file

In app/etc/di.xml change

Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink

to:

Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy

then :

`rm -rf var/cache/* var/generation/* var/page_cache/*`

`php bin/magento ca:c`

2. Or Changing settings in Configuration

(From https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/95077/44597)

Go to Stores => Configuration => Advanced => Developer => Template Settings and change Allow Symlinks => No

Answer (score 0):

Check your app/etc/config.php file is it there or not mostly this type of error occurs when config.php is missing