# Change language and icon doesn't show in Magento 2.2

Tags: magento2.2, language

I changed language from US to Persian, after that the icon doesn't show.
I did the solution that is in this link:
[admin backend icon fonts missing](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/113945/admin-backend-icon-fonts-missing)
But it didn't solve it, when I use

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

all content added to  en_US, I think if can change en_US to Persian the problem will be solved.